# Matrix algorithm for finding holes in matrix matching pattern

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I'm working on an application that attempts to assemble blocks of various shapes into the most compact matrix possible.  I'm looking for any existing algorithms that can "and" together two matrixes of differing sizes and return the upper right position in the first matrix where the 2nd matrix would fit.

For example:
Matrix A:

```
[1,0,1,1,1]
[1,0,0,1,1]
[1,0,0,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,1]
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

Matrix B:

```
[1,0]
[1,0]
[1,1]
```

There are 2 places Matrix B could fit within Matrix A - (0,1) and (1,2).
I could do this with a brute-force method (expand matrix B to match the size of matrix A, inverse Matrix A and "AND" them together.  Slide Matrix B to the right, then down until every possible position of the shape is represented).  Intuitively it seems like there should be a more efficient way of accomplishing the same using some matrix library or formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Baker-Bird algorithm (let's say it is an extension of KMP algorithm to two dimensions).
Please look up this topic, where You can find some more explanations: [2D String Matching: Baker-Bird Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847561/2d-string-matching-baker-bird-algorithm)